# Should we have Joel Spolsky as avid user?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I am aware this may be a bit out of the line, but I couldn't resist.

There's a user on PMSE who most of us probably know -- Joel Spolsky. At the moment [he has 180 reputation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/132/joel-spolsky) which means it takes only *two* upvotes to make Joel avid user of PMSE. It would have a number of positive effects:

- We need more avid users, and maybe, just maybe, there's some secret tweak that counts Joel twice or thrice or ten times.
- Joel (hopefully) won't allow to kill a site where he is avid user.
- It's cool to have such celebrity on the list of avid users.
- Joel would be counted in [reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/93/week/pm) so at least some of us would be able to feel they're better than Joel himself (as long as he don't start posting kickass answers like crazy)

Since Joel answered only a single question you know what needs to be done -- go to [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/25/how-to-estimate-amount-of-work-man-hours-for-an-unfamiliar-task/169#169) and upvote *good* answers.

And before you'd run the question to the ground, please not that [not every question on meta.stackoverflow is totally serious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

**DISCLAIMER:** This is NOT serious.  It's a joke.

Comment: Ok, I'll play along!  Has Joel ever killed something he belonged to before?  Has he ever blogged about starting something and then being the person to kill it?  Perhaps there is something in his blog posts?  My take:  He isn't scared.  He's above the celebrity status.  Thoughts?

Comment: Ok. Fount it!  March 18th.  Joel kills JoelOnSoftware, an extremely popular blog that he ran for 10 years.  If he'll kill that, he'll surely kill a fledgling site like ours.  [Wiki article on Joel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky).

Comment: If you want to be funny, I think we should down-vote him instead :) now THAT would be an unexpected surprise!

Comment: I wonder if there is a script that runs that prevents Joel from being downvoted?  Like he's impervious to downvotes like Superman is to bullets.

Answer (score 5):

Follow my advice here. :)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/

Seriously!

Answer (score 0):

Since Joel got two more upvotes, so my guess is the community has decided it is worth having him as an avid user.

Now let the magic happen. We'll see whether any of speculations was true :)

Comment: It's cool to have such celebrity already :D

Answer (score 0):

Joel is crazy about puppies.  Perhaps this fact could be used to lure him in.  :)